# External monitor via HDMI only outputs Desktop background and Unity launcher from 17.04

Tags: 17.04, hdmi, amd-graphics, external-monitor

I have connected my laptop via HDMI to my new big screen 1080p TV. I had set HDMI1 as source on TV, and instantly it shows video output from my laptop. But, there is this wierd problem.

It only outputs desktop background and Unity launcher (vertical on left side) and top horizontal bar.
No matter what is on the actuall screen on laptop (Firefox for example), it just shows desktop.

I have tried to change some settings in Ubuntu Settings - Displays. But nothing changes.

Specs:

HP G5 255 (laptop)
15,6 inch 1080p display
AMD A6-7310 APU with AMD Radeon R4 Graphics × 4 (1 GB allocated to iGPU)
Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS (DRM 2.49.0 / 4.10.0-28-generic, LLVM 4.0.0), Mesa 17.2.2
12 GB DDR3L 1600 MHz (4 + 8 GB)
Ubuntu 17.04 64-bit